# trouble with the_post_thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm trying to create a portfolio page that will display a series of thumbnails and, when clicked on, will go to single.php. The code I'm using below seems to work in that when I click "see more" it goes to the proper page, however the thumbnails are not showing up. Any ideas as to why? Thanks.

[Live site.](http://www.frshstudio.com)

work.php

```
    <?php query_posts('cat=4'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="portfolio-item">

            <?php //get article_image (custom field) ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )); ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"<img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image[0] ); ?>" alt="View more info" /></a>
            <p class="btn"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">See more</a></p>
        </div><!-- end portfolio-item -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php wp_reset_query();?>

</div><!-- end work -->
```

functions.php

```
<?php 


// unregister all default WP Widgets
    function unregister_default_wp_widgets() {
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Pages');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Calendar');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Archives');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Links');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Meta');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Search');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Text');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Categories');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Posts');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Comments');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_RSS');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud');
    }
    add_action('widgets_init', 'unregister_default_wp_widgets', 1);


// set thumbnail size    
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 130, 130, true ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions (cropped)



?>
```

Comment: Are you setting the image through the 'Featured Image', or is it a custom field?

Comment: 'Featured Image'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In your work.php code sample you are calling

`get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'the_post_thumbnail', true)`

This has nothing to do with WordPress post thumbnails and is looking for a custom field with the post meta key 'the_post_thumbnail'

#### For more info see:

- **[get_post_thumbnail_id](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id)**
- **[wp_get_attatchment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)**
- **[Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)**

***To get the src url of the featured image attached to the post and use WordPress post thumbnails***

change:

`<?php $image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_post_thumbnail', true); ?>`

to:

`<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ));`

when you echo the image:

`<img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image[0] ); ?>" alt="View more info" />`

The reason the array index [0] is added to $image is because wp_get_attachment_image_src returns an array(
[0] = img url attribute
[1] = img width
[2] = img height
)
To fix your php error add the missing `}` after your `if_function_exists() {` block.

**Note:** Unless your trying to make your theme backwards compatible to WordPress version 2.9 or earlier there is no need to call `if_function_exists()` on `add_theme_support()` or `register_sidebar()`

Comment: Thank you for your help. The error is fixed, and I've made your reccomended changes, however now in place of the thumbnail I see " alt="View more info" /> "

Comment: Also made the changes per your note, " alt="View more info" /> " problem persists.

Comment: Answer updated.  I forgot you need to use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to return just the src attribute.

Comment: IT is actually much easier to just use `the_post_thumbnail('image-size')`

Comment: Thanks for the update- it took care of the " alt="View more info" /> " issue, but still no thumbnails. I'll update work.php  in my original post to reflect the changes.

Comment: @Pippin, what do you mean? `the_post_thumbnail('image-size')` instead of `esc_url( $image[0] )`?

Comment: Your missing the closing `>` tag after the quotation marks after the_permalink().  And like Pippin mentioned its much easier to just use `the_post_thumbnail()`.  `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>`

Comment: Getting closer! Thumbnails now appear, however alt="View more info" /> is still showing?

`<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> alt="View more info" /></a>`

Comment: Use this: `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Go to functions.php and add this:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

This will enable theme support for post thumbnails, this way you can use featured image.
Then, add this to functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'portfoliothumbnail', xxx, yyy, true );
```

xxx is width you need for thumbnails, yyy is height.

After that, you can use featured images for post's and call them with:

```
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, "portfoliothumbnail", true);?>
```

Comment: I've already got that bit of info in my functions.php file. I'll post it all in my original post.

ETA: I didn't read through what you wrote carefully enough. I'll make those changes now. Thanks.